# What tribe is David from?

Tags: david

What tribe is King David from?

Comment: I've answered your main question. But you've then added lots of confusing points which are actually other questions. Please try to split them up. And would you also check out our [tour], since your questions will need to be well phrased to be acceptable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and advice I will take the tour.

Comment: I have edited your question to remove the parts which are irrelevant to the core question.  They may make for additional useful questions, however, they just aren't meaningful to answering this question.

Comment: Google search "What tribe is King David from?" and literally the first result is "Tribe of Judah" ..... just sayin :)

Comment: You were concerned about the East Gate as well. In the desert, the tribes of Judah, Issachar, and Zebulon camped to the East. Nearest the gate was [Judah](http://www.bibleexplained.com/moses/Numb/nu02.htm) " 3 - East side ... standard ... Judah They would have been directly in front of the gate or entrance to the courtyard and the tabernacle (although at some distance)."

Answer (score 9):

David is from the tribe of Judah. This can be found in [Matthew 1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+1&version=NIVUK). See [verses 2-6a](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+1%3A2-6&version=NIVUK):

> Abraham was the father of Isaac,
>
> Isaac the father of Jacob,
>
> Jacob the father of **Judah** and his brothers,
>
> Judah the father of Perez and Zerah, whose mother was Tamar,
>
> Perez the father of Hezron,
>
> Hezron the father of Ram,
>
> Ram the father of Amminadab,
>
> Amminadab the father of Nahshon,
>
> Nahshon the father of Salmon,
>
> Salmon the father of Boaz, whose mother was Rahab,
>
> Boaz the father of Obed, whose mother was Ruth,
>
> Obed the father of Jesse,
>
> and Jesse the father of **King David**.

Comment: Also [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=What+tribe+is+David+from%3F&oq=What+tribe+is+David+from%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) is pretty quick with the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

The tribe of Yehudah (Judah) hence Christ is called the conquering lion of Yehudah (Judah) being a descendant of King David whom was a descendant of Yehudah (Judah) whom was one of the 12 sons of Ya'akov (Jacob whom was renamed Yisrael) that make up the 12tribes of Yisrael. It is mentioned in sctipture time and time again.